# Append value to response text returned by ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to append value to response text that i am getting back from ajax request.

I used below code

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, response, settings) {
  var resp = response.responseText;       
});
```

Suppose i am getting response text

i.e

```
/home/xyz
```

and i want append

```
/home/xyz/abc
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question right, you can always do

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, response, settings) {
  var resp = response.responseText;
  var new_resp = resp + '/abc';
  window.location.href = new_resp;

});
```

Comment: yes i know how to do this. what i want to do is i am redirecting on certain page based on url. i want to append value to that url so that now i will be redirecting to new url